# My wireless adapter is "Hard blocked" - WN2001 on an ASRock AMD E350M1/USB3

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, rfkill

My wireless adapter is hard-blocked and i do not know how to fix it. I have tried the following:

- sudo rfkill unblock all
- sudo rmmod rtl8192cu && sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
- sudo rm /dev/rfkill
- sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower auto
- sudo ifconfig wlan0 up

My wireless adapted is the Prolink WN2001, my motherboard is a ASRock AMD E350M1/USB3.

Here's information from rfkill list all:

```
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Here's information from lshw -C network:

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 72:70:17:03:4d:61
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=3.5.0-22-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

If it helps, back when i was on windows i disabled the device via the driver application provided by prolink. I don't really want to have to reinstall windows just to enabled the wireless adapter again, so im hoping there is a solution.

Comment: Sounds silly, but please check the hardware switch. If it is enabled by `Fn+F<1-12>` key please try without `Fn` Key or vice versa.

Comment: Didnt work... It seems that the radio is turned off by some kind of onboard configuration on the device it self.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that on different drivers the adapters radio was "off", however on other drivers the radio was perfectly fine.

I just blacklisted the driver that was giving me the problem (RTL8192CU) and hoped a better one would kick in which it did :)

I had a backup plan to use a confirmed working driver from realtek (RTL8192SU), however i had a problem compiling the code.

Answer (score 0):

its working for me.

1. Connect your wifi adapter to your usb slot
2. Open startup application and add these commands

`sudo rmmod -f rtl8192cu`

`sudo modprobe rtl8192cu swenc=1 debug=5`

That command always loads when booting ubuntu

To use it, first restart..after ubuntu is power on, unplug your wifi adapter and plug it again..

wifi works are marked with glowing lights