How to activate wifi without using the "FN+F4" key combination in Ubuntu?
I have been trying to find out if it is possible to activate Wi-Fi in Ubuntu without the need for the "FN + F4" key combination, since in Windows this combination was not necessary for Wi-Fi to be automatically activated.
I visited several specialized forums, but I did not get a satisfactory answer. Below I leave my learning and attempts.
This is the version of my system:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

1 - As suggested by forums, I listed the networks using the "RF-KILL" command. I identified that the hardware was blocked, as expected
 rfkill list
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

2 - I then tried to unblock all of them using the following command. However, without success.
 rfkill unblock all

3 - Reload the kernel module of the Wi-Fi card, first trying to find out which module it was.
 lspci | grep -i network
 sudo modprobe -r module_name
 sudo modprobe module_name

4 - Unblock via ACPI, adding the second line of code. Don't forget to update the document.
 sudo nano /etc/default/grub - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux" 
 sudo update-grub 
 sudo reboot

5 - All the forums I searched before opening this question.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/276049/my-wireless-adapter-is-hard-blocked-wn2001-on-an-asrock-amd-e350m1-usb3

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-initial-check.html.pt-BR#:~:text=Notebooks%20geralmente%20possuem%20bot%C3%B5es%20de,que%20Wi%2DFi%20esteja%20ligado.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/158275/problemas-de-conex%c3%a3o-wifi-e-para-instalar-git-no-ubuntu-16-04

https://plus.diolinux.com.br/t/wi-fi-nao-aparece-no-ubuntu-20-04-resolvido/18516/27?page=2

